# Ansible Crontab Loading various files with identical content

Tags: list, ansible, cron

my issue with Ansible is that I want to create an Ansible job that generates a Crontab using data from files located in another folder. For example:

main.yaml
Folder - install

- install_job1.yaml
- install_job2.yaml
- ....

Currently, it only outputs the last file. I am not sure if hash_behaviour: merge is correct. My goal is to create files in the install folder with the same schema and have them automatically loaded without the need to edit the main.yaml file.

main.yaml:

```yaml
---
- name: Search for all Install
  include_vars:
    name: cron_data
    hash_behaviour: 'merge'
    file: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'install/*.yaml', wantlist=True) }}"
  vars:
    cron_data: { }
- name: Set crontab-entry
  cron:
    name: "{{ cron_job.name }}-{{ cron_job.job }}"
    minute: "{{ cron_job.minute }}"
    hour: "{{ cron_job.hour }}"
    weekday: "{{ cron_job.weekday | join(',') }}"
    job: " bash run_{{ cron_job.job}}.sh"
    disabled: "{{ cron_job.disabled }}"
  with_items: "{{ cron_data.jobs }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: cron_job
```

install_job1.yaml and install_job2.yaml are identical, except for their names.
install_job1.yaml

```yaml
---
jobs:
  - {
    name: install a,
    job: install Job a,
    hour: 16,
    minute: 15,
    weekday: [0,2,4,6],
    disabled: false
  }
  - {
    name: install b,
    job: install Job b,
    hour: 16,
    minute: 10,
   weekday: [1,3,5]
    disabled: true
  }
```

install_job2.yaml

```yaml
---
jobs:
  - {
    name: install g,
    job: install Job d,
    hour: 16,
    minute: 55,
    weekday: [1,3,5]
    disabled: false
  }
  - {
    name: install f,
    job: install Job e,
    hour: 16,
    minute: 18,
    weekday: [0,2,4,6],
    disabled: true
  }
```

When I load the files individually, it works:

```yaml
include_vars:
  file: path/to/file.yaml
```

How do I load all files from the folder and display them without listing each file individually?
Thanks